# How can I plot a surface generated by a function f(x,y) where the values x and y are subject to constraints?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm new to Matlab and I have a function

[image]

and

[image]

How can I plot:

[image]

Comment: FYI, Stack Overflow doesn't render LaTeX.

Comment: @edwinksl One of the unexpected benefits of Anki :) Just type a latex equation in, then drag & drop :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your `X` and `Y` in a linear array

```
X = linspace(-2, 2, 1000);
Y = linspace(-2, 2, 1000);
```

Mesh them so you have a grid of `x` and `y`

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(X,Y);
```

Get the value for your function

```
f = sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2);
```

Define your domain

```
D = (1 <= x.^2 + y.^2);
```

Set everything outside your domain to `nan`'s so it won't plot

```
f(~D) = nan;
```

Plot the surface

```
surf(x,y,f, 'linestyle', 'none')
```